# I want to change detail.php?id=4 to detail/4,but my .htaccess file not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

This  is my .htaccess file looks like

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s

RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^detail$ detail.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^detail/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ detail.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: For starters, can you output the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` here? It may just say where your .htaccess gets stuck... Maybe remove the `[NC,L]` lines at the end and see what it does?

Comment: Your .htaccess looks good. What is happening, and why do you think it is not working?

Comment: how it is not working, errors or no response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about using .htaccess to rewrite your URLs internally and route them appropriately to your application.

You should try with this specific .htaccess example that will do what you're looking for:

```
    RewriteEngine On

    # external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /detail(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ detail/%1? [R=302,L,NE]
    # internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^detail/([^/]+)/?$ detail.php?id=$1
```

EDITED:

Comment: This rule won't work. It just rewrites some id to index.php, which is not what OP is asking for.

Comment: Now it telling me this type of error , i tried to fix it but i can't 
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /D:/wamp64/www/RacconReview/detail/4 on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/5.6.19 Server at localhost Port 80

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the opposite in your htaccess, redirecting detail/4 to detail.php?id=4. In your question you say ?id=4 to /4.

So swap, edit and test